# A case where Lebesgue integrable implies Riemann integrable

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Let $I$ an interval on $\mathbb{R}$ such as $I=(a,b)$, with $a$ or $b$ could be equal to infinity.

And we have $f\in \mathcal{L}^1(I,\mathcal{B}(I), \lambda)$, then do we have always 
$$\int_{(a,b)}fd\lambda= \int_a^bf(x)dx$$and if not ! When we have this equality, knowing that $f\in \mathcal{L}^1(I,\mathcal{B}(I), \lambda)$?

Comment: Are you looking for this counterexample $f=\chi_{\mathbb Q}\in{\mathcal L}^1(0,1)\setminus {\cal R}(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take simply the characteristic function of the rationals $f = \chi_{\mathbb Q}$. $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable (and $\int fd\lambda$ = 0) but $f$ is not Riemann-integrable.

In the case of bounded functions over closed intervals, a Lebesgue-integrable function $f$ is Riemann-integrable iff the set of discontinuities of $f$ is a null set.

Comment: But in this example isn't the measure of the set of discontinuity is $0$ since it's $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: No: $f$ is nowhere continuous. Take any $x \in \mathbb R$. For every $\delta > 0$, you have $\sup_{y \in B_\delta(x)}f(y) = 1$ and $\inf_{y \in B_\delta(x)}f(y) = 0$.

Comment: I understand, so under the condition condition of ''continue a.e" we have every lebesgue integrable function is Riemann integrable function.

Comment: I edited my answer. This is true for bounded functions over closed intervals. I don't think this is true in general.

Comment: well that doesn't anwser my question, because I have an integrable function on $[0,1]$ and I need to go from Lebesgue integral to Reimann integral.

Comment: Could be wrong, but a function being Lebesgue integrable is theoretically irrelevant as to whether it's Riemann integrable. A function is Riemann integrable iff its set of discontinuities has measure zero. Being Lebesgue integrable doesn't gain you anything, so far as I can make out.